# Create a list that contains a numeric value for each response to a categorical variable

Tags: r

I have a df with a categorical value which has 2 levels: Feed, Food

```
structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Feed", "Food"), class = "factor")
```

I want to create a list with a numeric value to match each categorical variable (ie. Feed = 0, Food = 1)
The list matches with the categorical variable to form 2 columns

Probably very simple...every time I've attempted to put the two together, both columns have ended up numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Feed", "Food"), class = "factor")

df <- tibble("foods" = df)

df %>% 
  mutate(numeric = as.numeric(foods))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  foods numeric
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 Food        2
2 Food        2
3 Feed        1
4 Food        2
5 Feed        1
6 Food        2
```

Or like this if you want 0/1 as numbers.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(numeric = as.numeric(foods) - 1)
```

Comment: this works for this df with only 6 observations...is there a way to apply this to a df with over 1000 observations? going through each individual case then would be extremely tedious. This is why I thought using a list of factors might be more effective then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This approach also works for more than 6 rows and more than 2 factor levels (try with this data: (df <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Feed", "Food", "Fish", "Summer"), class = "factor")). Or do you mean how to apply this to more than one column?

Comment: I was trying figure out how to apply it to my original dataset but the original dataset. Played around with my code and this worked :)